# how to remove duplicate numbers from unsorted array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, hashmap, big-o

I was given the following question in a technical interview:

How do i remove duplicates from an unsorted array?

One option I was thinking of:

1. Create a hash map with the frequency of each number in the array
2. Go through the array and do a O(1) lookup in the hash map. If the frequency > 0, remove the number from the array.

Is there a more efficient way?

Another option

1. Sort the array O(nlog n) using quick sort or merge sort
2. Then iterate through the array and remove duplicates

Why is option 1 better than option 2?

I cannot use any functions that already do the work like array_unique.

Comment: "I cannot use any functions that already do the work like array_unique" - why?

Comment: its a technical interview question they gave me

Comment: If you cannot use existing functionality, then all language tags are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of removing the object from the array if the hash map says there is a duplicate, why don't you build a new array for each item in the hash map, and only add it to the array if there isn't a duplicate? The idea is to save the extra step of having 2 arrays with equal overhead at the start. PHP sucks at garbage collection so if you start with a massive array, even though you unset its value, it might still be hanging around in memory.

Comment: That also might be the explanation for the question "Why is option 1 better than option 2?"

Answer (score 0):

For the first option, time complexity is O(n); because creating as hash map O(n) and iterating through the array O(n), so in total O(n).

For the second option, time complexity is O(log(n)); because sort O(log(n)) and iterating O(n), so in total O(log(n)).

Clearly first option is better. Hope this helps:)

Comment: Assuming that we have to remove duplicates as mentioned in the question and there fore cannot create a new array.

Comment: the second option uses space. How do we take into account space when determining whether an algorithm is best?

Comment: effectiveness of an algorithm is based on both space and time. However to decide which algorithm to use totally depends on the situation in which you want to use the algorithm. If you cannot afford additional space, you should be using an algorithm which has better space complexity.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no constraints on creating another data structure to track state but must mutate the array in-place and only remove duplicates without sorting, then a variant of your first option may be best.

I propose you make a hashmap as you iterate the array, use the array values as keys and any garbage (boolean set to TRUE perhaps) as the value. As you encounter each item in the array (which is O(n)), check the map. If it exists, delete the item from the array, if not add they key-value pair. No need to track count, you only need to track what has been encountered.

Many languages have a built-in `set` abstract data type which basically perform this operation on a construction or `add all` operation. If you can provide a separate data structure with duplicates removed, just create a new set with the array's items and let that data structure remove duplicates.